# Problems with with keyup.enter on vuetify v-text-field

Tags: forms, vue.js, vuetify.js, keydown

I have a `v-text-field` from a `vuetify` form that calls a method but when I use the `@keydown.enter` event it does **not work**. With other keys, for example `@keydown.esc`, and with the button `<v-btn @click="submit">` it works. The vuetify version is `vuetify@2.3.21`. The following example illustrates the problem:

```html
<form>
  <v-text-field
    v-model="sepalLength"
    required
    @keydown.enter="submit" # HERE IS THE PROBLEM!!!
  ></v-text-field>  
  <v-btn @click="submit">Search</v-btn> # HERE IT WORKS
</form> 
<p style="white-space: pre-line;" v-if="predictedClass">{{ predictedClass }}</p>

<script>
data: () => ({
      predictedClass : ''
    }),
    methods: {
    submit () {
      axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict', { 
        sepal_length: this.sepalLength
      })
      .then((response) => {
        this.predictedClass = response.data.class
      })
</script>
```

Comment: ur in a form and u use a SPA, can you try to add `event.preventDefault();` in your submit function first line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try either this

```html
<form>
  <v-text-field
    v-model="sepalLength"
    required
    @keydown.enter="submit" # HERE IS THE PROBLEM!!!
  ></v-text-field>  
  <v-btn @click="submit">Search</v-btn> # HERE IT WORKS
</form> 
<p style="white-space: pre-line;" v-if="predictedClass">{{ predictedClass }}</p>

<script>
data: () => ({
      predictedClass : ''
    }),
    methods: {
    submit (event) { //<---- add event param
      event.preventDefault() //<---------------HERE
      axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict', { 
        sepal_length: this.sepalLength
      })
      .then((response) => {
        this.predictedClass = response.data.class
      })
</script>
```

or the short hand

```html
<form>
  <v-text-field
    v-model="sepalLength"
    required
    @keydown.enter.prevent="submit" <----------prevent here
  ></v-text-field>  
  <v-btn @click="submit">Search</v-btn> # HERE IT WORKS
</form> 
<p style="white-space: pre-line;" v-if="predictedClass">{{ predictedClass }}</p>

<script>
data: () => ({
      predictedClass : ''
    }),
    methods: {
    submit () {
      axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict', { 
        sepal_length: this.sepalLength
      })
      .then((response) => {
        this.predictedClass = response.data.class
      })
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

by default, an HTML-form will call the `@submit`-binding when you press enter while any field has focus.

*Note: The `.prevent`-modifier will prevent the page from reloading; so you can run some code.*

A HTML button of `type="sumbit"` would call the forms `@submit`-binding.

#### Therefore a better approach would be:

```html
<template>
  <!-- bind function when the form submits (by pressing `Enter` or clikcing a button with type `submit`) -->
  <form @submit.prevent="submit">
    ...
    <!-- Call the forms @submit-binding -->
    <button type="submit">
      Submit
    </button>

  </form>
</template>

<script>
methods: {
  submit() {
    // so stuff
  }
}
</script>
```